# Prove completely regular space has the initial topology of all continuous functions into the unit interval

Tags: general-topology

From the definition, for a completely regular spaces $X$, a nonempty open set $U\subset X$, and a point $x\in U$, there exists a cts $f: X\to[0,1]$ s.t. $f(X-U)=0$ and $f(x)=1$. Then $x\in f^{-1}((1/2,1])\subset U$. Does this qualify as a proof of the statement in the title?
But aren't we supposed to show there are finitely many cts funcitons $f_i: X\to [0,1]$ such that $x\in \cap_1^nf_i^{-1}(V_i)\subset U$? I can't seem to find a proof in a textbook. That is, open preimages should only be a subbase, not a base, right? Thanks.

**Update**

It seems, in this particular case, preimages of open sets in $[0,1]$ do indeed form a base, not just a subbase, due to the following fact:

> For $V_1, \cdots, V_n$ open sets of $[0,1]$, and $f_1,\cdots, f_n$ cts functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$, the intersection $U':=\cap_1^n f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ is open in $\tau$, and so, for every $x\in U'$, by definition of completely regularity, there exists a cts $f:X\to [0,1]$ s.t. $f(X-U')=0$ and $f(x)=1$. So $U'':=f^{-1}((1/2,1])\subset U'$.

That is, we don't need finite intersections of open preimages to from a base, the open preimages themselves do form a base!! Based on @Chad_K's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the topology on $X$ and $\tau_w$ be the initial topology from all continuous functions to $[0,1]$.  Your argument shows that members of $\tau_w$ are a base for $\tau$.  So every member of $\tau$ is a union of members of $\tau_w$, so every member of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau_w$.  So $\tau\subseteq \tau_w$.

For the other direction, let $x\in S\in\tau_w$.  By definition there are sets $V_1,\ldots,V_n\subseteq [0,1]$ such that $V_i$ are open in $[0,1]$ and continuous functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ such that $x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^n f_i^{-1}(V_i)\subseteq S$.  But each $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ is $\tau$-open because the $f_i$ are continuous.  So $\bigcap_{i=1}^n f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ is $\tau$-open.  This shows that members of $\tau$ are a base for $\tau_w$.  So by similar argument to above, $\tau_w\subseteq \tau$.

Comment: It seems to me $\tau_w\subset \tau$ is an automatic fact, and requires no proof at all. My question really is about, shouldn't preimages of open sets only form a subbase, not a base?

Comment: @user760:  If $V\subseteq[0,1]$ is open and $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ continuous, sets of the form $f^{-1}(V)$ are a *subbase* for $\tau_w$.  They also turn out to be a base for $\tau$.  That's not a problem.  It just means that a space being 'completely regular' is more demanding that saying $\tau=\tau_w$.

Comment: Thanks! So in this case, open preimages form a subbase that is also a base! I didn't realize that.